# Регистр и подсветка слов

Tags: php

Имеется код который должен подсвечивать слова в поиске но он подсвечивает только слова которые идут подряд (stack overflow) а если искать (overflow stack) ничего не подсветит и если эти слова стоят так (stack super overflow) ничего не подстветит и вообще он чувствителен к регистру слов

```
$searchq = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
```

...

```
$searchValue = str_replace($searchq, '<b class="lttl_str">' 
    . $searchq  . '</b>', $row['data']);
```

как это исправить?

спасибо

Comment: searchq=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$searchValue = str_replace($searchq, 
  '<b class="lttl_str">'.$searchq.'</b>',
  $row['data']); Вот такой код у меня сейчас

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас не имеет значения регистр слов и их порядок, нужно перед "подсвечиванием" разбивать запрос на слова и подсвечивать каждое отдельно. Также соответственно осуществлять поиск без учета регистра, но при этом переводить в нужный регистр найденное слово (либо не изменять найденное).

Например так:

```
// режем запрос на слова (можно использовать explode(' ', $searchq),
// но при появлении повторяющихся разделителей они не будут группироваться)
$words = preg_split('/ +/', $searchq);
// экранируем символы "опасные" для регулярных выражений
$quoted_words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);
// собираем регулярное выражение
$pattern = '/' . implode('|', $quoted_words) . '/i';
// "подсвечиваем" каждое слово
$searchValue = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>$0</b>', $row['data']);
```

Если потребуется работа с юникодом, то код нужно будет дополнить